# 100 % CPU by IIS process by Service Model-4 module after the wcf request has passed

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I have a problem I'm fighting for a week now. I have a WCF service running in IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2 and a windows service client who is making one or two requests at each 30 seconds. At some point (usually withing two hours of the service running) one of the requests is causing the service app pool (separated from other app pools) process to gain CPU usage. In IIS worker process section can be seen that this request never ends and is hanging in ServiceModel-4 module in AuthenticateRequest state (i.e most likely it is in infinite loop somewhere). At some point another such request is added to the first one, until they become four, staying forever and causing 100 % CPU usage (there are 4 logical processors on the machine). What I did to investigate , fix this problem:

- used wcf tracing and custom logging to determine where the problem is. Wcf tracing actually shows all the requests made to the server passed succesfully in milliseconds (!) (at the same time wcf tracing on the client side shows of course time out on the same requests). Custom logging also is showing that the service code is calling returtn of the requested operation. The result of the method are two simple dto objects, so no possible serialization issue and also there are no enpoint behaviors or wathever custom code which is execting before sending reply from the service (except the method code, which, as I mentioned returns successfully).
- used iis failed request tracing which shows the request reaching the ServiceModel-4 without continuing with the following information:
  ModuleName : ServiceModel-4.0
  Notification: AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST
  HttpStatus: 500
  HttpReason: Internal Server Error
  HttpSubStatus: 0
  ErrorCode: The operation completed succesfully (0x0)
- used Debug Diag for tracing requests continuing more than 10 minutes and saw the threads which are running long time. The stack trace is as follows:

[image: Callstack1]

or as follows:

[image: Callstack2]

I've seen these are called from iis process. Since thiese are .Net function I suspected first corrupted .Net installation, moreover there were both .Net4.5 and .Net4 installed on the server (which I don't know how exactly could happen). So:

- I deinstalled .Net4 and From windows features on/off i turned off .Net4.5 features, restarted and after that i turned them on, restarted, without success
- after that I by same way reinstalled the IIS (from Windows features). Again no success.

Does not have any more ideas.

Comment: Do you have any multi threading code running internally in the hosted code, which can pump up the CPU, and possibly going in an infinite loop, a there's no exit available, thus infinitely consume the resources. I would recommend using a Dot Trace profiler and check what are methods holding on the execution, it would be much more descriptive than other windows debugging tools.

Answer (score 1):

it seems I have found the answer (but havent used Dot Trace or other tools). There was an access to a Generic Dictionary from multiple threads. This seems to be a known problem:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2009/12/21/high-cpu-in-net-app-using-a-static-generic-dictionary/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2009/05/11/asp-net-application-100-cpu-caused-by-system-collections-generic-dictionary/

Actually I noticed this problem in the beggining of the research but ruled it out, because i couldn't reproduce it (probably because I havent't testing the dictionary in iis app, of course I received various exceptions, but not a 100 % Cpu) and mainly because all logs showed that the code, accessing the dictionary has passed, also the stack trace above has nothing to do with the dictionary.

However I think that the problem happened during the serialization of this dictionary (which is data contract) which explains the logged information. 
Still cannot explain how this exactly is happening. If anyone can explain it I think it will be a good knowledge for everyone.

Comment: Hi, generally there is not a problem to use Generic Dictionary as a Data Contract as long as it is accessed in a thread safe manner both for reading and writting in the code. This is of course valid for all use case scenarios of a Generic Dictionary, but the problem was very "hidden" in the "Data Contract" scenario, because it happened during the serialization of the dictionary, after the custom application code has already finished with all operations with the dictionary.

Comment: On the other hand, using a dictionary as a Data Contract is not a good practice according to me, because:
1) Dictionary is a .NET thing and may not be well supported for different than .NET clients of your service.
2) Dictionary is not extensible - if you use a simple types as a key-value and at some point you need to add more information to this, you have to change the data contract, instead of just making non-breaking extention to it.

Comment: Therefore I would reccommend to just use a custom object instead of a dictionary as a Data Contract. You can still use dictionary for performance reasons in your code if needed (and also a ConcurrentDictionary if you have multithreaded access to it) and convert it to custom object as a Data Contract at the end